# how to unzip 'zg-files' output files in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script in python that allows me to download sequences of a species that the user enters the name "input" then his sequences are placed directly in a folder that takes the name of the species. But in zipped format (_genomic.fna.gz or _protein.faa.gz). I would like to add a function that allows to zip directly the output files (because it's an important number for example for klebsiella almost 14 000 sequences). Si quelqu'un peut m'aider s'il vous plaît( en rajoutant . here is my code :

```
import wget
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd   
import urllib.parse
import posixpath 
import os
import gzip
import shutil

URL='https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/GENOME_REPORTS/prokaryotes.txt'

data = pd.read_csv(wget.download(URL) , sep = '\t', header = 0)

espece = input("bacterial species : ")
TypeSeq = input ("fna (nucleique) ? ou faa (proteique) ? : ")   

if data["#Organism/Name"].str.contains(espece, case = False).any():

    print(data.loc[data["#Organism/Name"].str.contains(espece, case = False)]['Status'].value_counts())  
    FTP_list = data.loc[data["#Organism/Name"].str.contains(espece, case = False)]["FTP Path"].values
if  TypeSeq == "faa" :
    
        if not os.path.exists(espece):
            os.makedirs(espece)
    
        for url in FTP_list:
            try : 
                parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
                parts.path
                posixpath.basename(parts.path)
                suffix = "_protein.faa.gz"
                prefix = posixpath.basename(parts.path) 
                print(prefix+suffix)
                path = posixpath.join(parts.path, prefix+suffix)
                ret = parts._replace(path=path) 
                sequence = wget.download(urllib.parse.urlunparse(ret), out=espece)
                f = gzip.open(sequence, 'rb')
                    
            except :
                print ("")
        
else:    
    print("species not found ")
```

Comment: In the title you say you want to "decompress gz files". In the question itself you say you want to "zip directly the output files". Please clarify.

Comment: the output files are gz files

Comment: You already use `gzip.open`. Did you check the examples of usage for `gzip` in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage ?

Comment: Yes I looked, I have several files, not just one. I did not find an example with several files